# Is it possible to subscribe an observable on child window?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-components

Based on the example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-open-window

I created an observable on app component and tried to subscribe it in the pop-up window (window component) through a shared service, but It does not reflect. What is the proper way of achieving this?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-open-window-pxeuj4

Comment: I couldn't find any observables in the Stackblitz example.

Comment: Added the example.